# Python insert to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert some values from python to MySQL and I receive the following error.

Connection and code in Python:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="lpr",passwd="B1ack53@",db="lpr")
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO liccaptured(realtime, proctime, plate, confid, uuid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", realtime,proctime,plate,confid,uuid)
```

Error message:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO liccaptured(realtime, proctime, plate, confid, uuid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", realtime,proctime,plate,confid,uuid)
TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (7 given)
```

I tried looking for similar errors and could not figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are running into comes from the fact that you are treating the `cursor.execute` method as one which accepts a variable number of arguments:

```
c.execute(operation, arg1, arg2, ..., argn)  # won't work
```

`execute` only accepts a fixed number of arguments though. The paramaters to the SQL statement itself are passed in as a single argument that is a tuple:

```
my_args = (arg1, arg2, ..., argn)
c.execute(operation, my_args)                  # this will work
c.execute(operation, (arg1, arg2, ..., argn))  # just the same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message says everything: the function `execute` has at most 3 arguments, but you're calling it with 7 arguments. So you just need to call it properly with 3 arguments.

According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), `execute` function's syntax is as follows:

`cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)`

- `operation` is SQL query as string
- `params` is an array of parameters
- `multi` is boolean flag

Answer (score 0):

You did not correctly pass the tuple string operator. Consequently, `c.execute()` assumes multiple arguments. Simply, place `%` just after string with no commas, and wrap all variables in parentheses

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO liccaptured (realtime, proctime, plate, confid, uuid) \
           VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" % (realtime,proctime,plate,confid,uuid))
```

Alternatively, consider using [string format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO liccaptured (realtime, proctime, plate, confid, uuid) \
           VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})".format(realtime,proctime,plate,confid,uuid))
```